# how to take cell size from raster using python or GDAL or RASTERIO

Tags: python, gdal, python-2.7, rasterio

How to take cell size per X,Y using simple python or `GDAL` or `RASTERIO`?
and hot to count how many pixels have my raster with some packages..

I have find some code but is pyqgis and I don't need this package :

```
ras  = QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/myname/raster.tif")
pixelSizeX= ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeY = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

print pixelSizeX
print pixelSizeY
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With PyQGIS

```
ras  = QgsRasterLayer("raster.tif")
pixelSizeX= ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeY = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
print pixelSizeX
2.11668210081
print pixelSizeY
2.11685012701
```

With GDAL

```
from osgeo import gdal
raster = gdal.Open('raster.tif')
gt =raster.GetGeoTransform()
print gt
(258012.37107330866, 2.11668210080698, 0.0, 163176.6385398821, 0.0, -2.1168501270110074)
pixelSizeX = gt[1]
pixelSizeY =-gt[5]
print pixelSizeX
2.11668210080698
print pixelSizeY
2.1168501270110074
```

With Rasterio

```
import rasterio
raster =  rasterio.open('raster.tif')
gt = raster.affine
print gt
Affine(2.11668210080698, 0.0, 258012.37107330866,
   0.0, -2.1168501270110074, 163176.6385398821)
pixelSizeX = gt[0]
pixelSizeY =-gt[4]
print pixelSizeX
2.11668210080698
print pixelSizeY
2.1168501270110074
```

Or (from sgillies)

```
pixelSizeX, pixelSizeY  = raster.res
print pixelSizeX
2.11668210081
print pixelSizeY
2.11685012701
```

Comment: thank you very much,can I use GDAL or RASTERIO to take complete metadata one by one in specific variables like `pixelSizeX`,`pixelSizeY`?Because now I use some algorithms from GDAL and some from RASTERIO in the some function and my app is slowly I thing.

Comment: Yes, without problem, look at  [the Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) for example

Comment: in page with get raster metadata have only specific I need all

Comment: Gene, better to do `pxsz, pysz = raster.res` with Rasterio.

Comment: Just to make things smoother, the command for opening raster in gdal is `gdal.Open('raster.tif')` (with 'O')

Comment: I tried it with rasterio but I have an issue `DatasetReader object has no attribute affine`

Comment: Using Rasterio 1.0.15, `gt = raster.affine` should be `gt = raster.transform`

Comment: Can someone please time each of these approches?

Comment: With the new rasterio version (mine is 1.1.5), there is no `raster.affine`
Instead, we need to use `gt = raster.transform`