# Getting pixel size without opening raster using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, resolution, ppygis

I want to get the pixel size (resolution) of a raster without opening up the raster in gdal. I currently have my script opening the raster in GDAL using `gdal.Open()` and getting the resolution that way. However this process is slow especially when my TIFFs are large and I have many of them.

```
from osgeo import gdal
data_path = "some/path/to/raster.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(data_path)
# md = ds.GetMetadata() # read metadata
gt = raster.GetGeoTransform()

pixelSizeX = gt[1]
pixelSizeY =-gt[5]
```

Is there a way to grab this info from the metadata or something without opening the file?

Comment: Post up an example of the code you're using.  Just calling `gdal.Open()` shouldn't be too expensive without actually reading any data

Comment: You will have to open the raster to get that information. More details here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243648/8104

Comment: Aaron is right, unless you have world files, in which case you ould just read the world file which would be a smaller memeory footprint (a few lines of text) compared to the whole image