# Python function to determine x and y extent of a raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have been using `gdal_grid` to convert xyz files to a raster

I am wondering is there anyway to automatically detect the extents to use from the xyz file `txe and tye` using python so that I can use a more general code every time I grid?

This way I will be stating my input xyz file and interpolation method but the raster extents will be pre-calculated for best results using python??

e.g.

```
gdal_grid  -a nearest:radius1=1.0:radius2=1.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe [pre-calculated] -tye [pre-calculated] -tr 1 1 "input" output
```

Comment: Are you interested in the greatest extent of the raster file or a polygon that represents the non-NoData values in that raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read the xyz file and the [`bounds`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dataset-georeferencing) method to get the bounding box of the dataset. For example ([sample data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inbo/niche_vlaanderen/master/tests/data/mlw_small.xyz)):

```
import rasterio

xyz = '/temp/small.xyz'

dataset = rasterio.open(xyz)
dataset.bounds
```

Which would yield:

```
Out[1]: BoundingBox(left=172762.5, bottom=210787.5, right=172937.5, top=210637.5)
```

Then you can pull individual coords from the bounding box object:

```
dataset.bounds[3]
```

Which would yield:

```
Out[1]: 210637.5
```

Comment: @fuzzy_raster9873 Yes, Rasterio can calculate cell size too: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243648/8104

Comment: I've just noticed that some of my xyz datasets using the above code are getting the error ```rasterio.errors.RasterioIOError: Ungridded dataset: At line 48, change of Y direction```. Does the dataset have to be gridded in order to use the above code? It was the extents I wanted for the gdal_grid command

Comment: I suspect that some of your xyz files do not follow the specification "no missing value is supported": https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html. Here is a possible solution to fill in missing values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596664/1446289.